# getByText doesn't find the element

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to see if at least part of text is rendered..

```
<li>
   Click here &nbsp;
   <a
     id="myLink"
     className="xxxxx"
     target="_blank"
     rel="noreferrer"
     href="https://www.aaa.com"
   >
      to open xxx.
   </a>
</li>
```

and test fails with:

```
xxxxxx.getByText('Click here')
```

but works fine if 'Click here' is only the text of that

is there a method to do partial search?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you pass a string to `getByText()`, it will look for that exact string. You can instead pass a regular expression to look for a partial match:

```js
x.getByText(/click here/i)
```

Here I used the `i` flag for a case insensitive search, but you could also pass a case sensitive regex: `/Click here/`.

---

From [About Queries > Using Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#using-queries):

> The primary argument to a query can be
> a *string*,
> *regular expression*,
> or *function*.
> There are also options to adjust how node text is parsed.
> See [TextMatch](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#textmatch)
> for documentation on what can be passed to a query.

From [TextMatch > Precision](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#precision):

> Queries that take a `TextMatch`
> also accept an object as the final argument
> that can contain options
> that affect the precision of string matching:
>
> - `exact`: Defaults to `true`; matches full strings, case-sensitive. When false, matches substrings and is not case-sensitive.
>
>   - `exact` has no effect on `regex` or `function` arguments.
>   - In most cases using a regex instead of a string gives you more control over fuzzy matching and should be preferred over `{ exact: false }`.